# if x in [list] iterator

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

```
def new_user() -> str:
    users = []
    print("Welcome to The 'Create New User' Interface")
    sleep(0.5)
    x = input("Enter Name to Use for Account Access\n*Name is Case Sensitive to Access Account*: ")
    if x in users:
        x = input("That User Already Exists! Enter a New Name: ")
        users.append(x)
        print("Your Account Access Name is: " + str(x))
    else:
        users.append(x)
        print("Your Account Access Name is: " + str(x))
```

So I'm not sure how to word this question but I have this block of code and as you can see I want to check if the user inputted name already exists, and if it does it'll prompt for a new name and add it to the list, and if it doesn't already exist, it'll add it to the list, but there's a way around this, if the list already contains a name and the user inputs that same name the `if x in users:` code will run and when prompted to enter another name, if they enter that same name, it wont recognize that it already exists and add it to the list either way, how can i prevent this?

Comment: Your function does not return anything. `users` is a local variable. It is created empty every time you call the function.

Comment: One more thing, in this context `str(x)` is exactly the same as `x`. Save yourself a function call.

Comment: my bad the return is x, its used for a bigger part of code, but my problem lies here, and for the 'users' thing, i made the list outside of function and still get the same result, i can bypass the initial check by inputting the same name after being prompted to enter a new name

Answer (score 0):

To get valid user input wrap the request in a loop and when you have valid input `break` out, e.g.:

```
print("Enter Name to Use for Account Access")
print("*Name is Case Sensitive to Access Account*")
while True:
    x = input("Enter a Name: ")
    if x not in users:  # Valid input
        break
    print("That User Already Exists!")

users.append(x)
print("Your Account Access Name is:", x)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

```
users = []
print("Welcome to The 'Create New User' Interface")
x = input("Enter Name to Use for Account Access\n*Name is Case Sensitive to Access Account*: ")
while x in users:
    x = input("That User Already Exists! Enter a New Name: ")
users.append(x)
print("Your Account Access Name is: " + str(x))
```

Simply just changed your `if` loop to a `while` loop that will continue until a unique name is given.

**Suggestions**

```
users = []
print("Welcome to The 'Create New User' Interface")
while True:
    user_name = '' #now users can not enter a empty user_name
    while not user_name:
        user_name = input("Enter Name to Use for Account Access: ")
    for i in range(0, len(users)): #different loop to enable use of lower()
        while  user_name.lower() == users[i].lower(): #removes need for unique cases
            print("That User Already Exists!")
            user_name = '' #again stopping empty fields
            while not user_name:
                user_name = input("Enter Name to Use for Account Access: ")
    users.append(user_name)     
    print("Your Account Access Name is: " + user_name)
```

For start we can create a loop that will reject any blank `user_name`.

Next we can use `.lower()` when checking to see if `user_name` exists in `users[]`.  By doing this we can preserve the unique case format the user wants to use to store their name(perhaps for display purposes) but at the same time we can check to see if `user_name` already exists regardless of case format.

Cleaning it up we can go with something like this:

```
 def ask_user(message=''): #create function to check for blank inputs
    user_name = ''
    while not user_name:
        user_name = input(message)
    return user_name

users = []
print("Welcome to The 'Create New User' Interface")
while True:
    user_name = ask_user("Enter Name to Use for Account Access: ")
    for i in range(0, len(users)):
        while  user_name.lower() == users[i].lower():
            print("\nThat User Already Exists!") #newline for clarity
            user_name = ask_user("Enter Name to Use for Account Access: ")
    users.append(user_name)     
    print("\nYour Account Access Name is: " + user_name) #newline for clarity
```

Here I created `ask_user` which handles blank inputs. Then added a `\n` in a few spots to help with readability.

**Output**

> ```
> (xenial)vash@localhost:~/pcc/10$ python3 helping.py
> Welcome to The 'Create New User' Interface
> Enter Name to Use for Account Access: 
> Enter Name to Use for Account Access: vash
>
> Your Account Access Name is: vash
> Enter Name to Use for Account Access: VASH
>
> That User Already Exists!
> Enter Name to Use for Account Access: 
> Enter Name to Use for Account Access: p0seidon
>
> Your Account Access Name is: p0seidon
> Enter Name to Use for Account Access: P0SEidoN
>
> That User Already Exists!
> ```

Hope this helps!